I wanted to make a hole in the sphere, but it turned out that it is not translucent, although there was a cavity earlier
The first screenshot shows how to make it work, and the second one shows how it works at the moment, although I do everything according to the same principle.



Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. Could you edit your post and translate all text to English? If you are not comfortable writing it yourself, feel free to use any automated online translation service.

Yes, no problem. Thank you for informing me
